# Could anyone advise me regarding the best tool to make databases highly available?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, high-availability

I need to make the database layer highly available to the application that we use. My supervisor is recommending ha-jdbc, but the document is absolutely not usable with hibernate. Any advice regarding any alternative solution?

Comment: Please define "highly available" in your context.  In itself it's just a buzzword without any distinct technical meaning.

Comment: what i want is something like this. if one of the database connection goes off, the other one still works, and the user does not get any interruption.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than abstracting the problem up a layer at the driver level, it might be better to concentrate on building a high availability database system. There are many things to think about and you'd probably get a better response on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I'd have to agree. I can't even recall the last time I had an "information" outage that was caused by a database problem. I've had disk failures (not hot-swappable, so had to take the server and database down), extended power failures, earthquakes, Internet connection failures . . .

Comment: None of these things (apart from maybe the earthquake) should take your database down. Disk failure - use RAID, power failure - use dual PSUs with UPS on each to give you time to role swap your master and slave, network failures - use dual NICs on different networks. This are the things that make a DB *high availability* and serverfault is the place to get help.

Comment: what if the house burns? lol, listen people take it easy, i have found one solution, it took me almost two days. ha-jdbc does the job quite good. just want to know if there are more.

Comment: @user582862 Are you telling me you don't have your DB server sat in a server room with a controlled environment and an automated halon fire supression system? Shame on you!